# Automatic text wrapping in Tikz bar charts?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, line-breaking

I am trying to get multiple bar charts (4 per page) in a LaTeX document. The issue is with the title and label text of some charts. It's showing results of a survey, some questions had long text and response text. Is there a way to get a tikz chart to 'automagically' line break/wrap the text of questions or responses? I've tried manually adding `\\` but that doesn't work and is problematic because I am using a macro from spreadsheet to programatically create the TeX code anyway so can't necessarily manually add `\\` or other break characters. It would be ideal if PGF/TikZ/LaTeX could automatically wrap text to make it fit.

Here's an MWE without showing the 4 charts per page but the problem is still evident. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,bmargin=1.3cm,footskip=5cm,headsep=0.3cm,landscape]{geometry}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % caused compilation errors!
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering % automatically center floats
\makeatother

\tikzset{
        hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
        hatch distance=10pt,
        hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
        hatch thickness=2pt
    }
    
        \makeatletter
    \pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{flexible hatch}
    {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    {\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
    {\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
    {
        \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }

\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand\qText{My school provides me with information about my next steps, for example, choosing qualifications for the futue, going to university or other education and training options like apprenticeships, or finding a job.}
\newcommand\resA{Yes, I received the right amount of information that was helpful}
\newcommand\valA{48}
\newcommand\resB{Yes, but it was too much information and was not helpful}
\newcommand\valB{23}
\newcommand\resC{Yes, but there wasn’t enough information that was helpful}
\newcommand\valC{29}
\newcommand\resD{No, I haven't received any information}
\newcommand\valD{0}
\newcommand\resE{}
\newcommand\valE{0}
\newcommand\ncount{305}
  \begin{axis}[
        axis on top,
        height=5cm,
        xmin=0,
       %width=\textwidth,
        bar width=0.6cm,
        %ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
        enlarge y limits=true,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line*=left,
        y axis line style={opacity=0},
        ytick=data,
        %tickwidth=0pt,
        enlarge x limits=false,
    title={`\textbf{\qText}'},
    xbar,
    xlabel={\% of Respondents},
    symbolic y coords={{\resE}, {\resD}, {\resC}, {\resB}, {\resA}},
    %ytick=data,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    ]
    \addplot[draw=blue!45, samples=100,
        pattern=flexible hatch,
        pattern color=blue!45] coordinates {(\valA,{\resA}) (\valB,{\resB}) (\valC,{\resC}) (\valD,{\resD}) (\valE,{\resE})};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a some of packages in your MWE that have nothing to do with the plot, so I removed them from the code below. I also added the missing `\makeatother` after the block with `\pgfdeclarepatternformonly`.

To have line breaks in the title, you can use the option `title style`, to style the y ticks, use `y tick label style`. You essentially need to tell PGF that you want the contents of the text node to align (right, center or left) and specify a concrete (maximum) text width. Line breaking will then be applied automatically.

You may want to adjust the spacing a bit. Above all, you need to increase the height of the plot if the y labels contain line breaks.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,bmargin=1.3cm,footskip=5cm,headsep=0.3cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
%\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
        hatch distance/.store in=\hatchdistance,
        hatch distance=10pt,
        hatch thickness/.store in=\hatchthickness,
        hatch thickness=2pt
    }
    
    \makeatletter
    \pgfdeclarepatternformonly[\hatchdistance,\hatchthickness]{flexible hatch}
    {\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
    {\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
    {\pgfpoint{\hatchdistance-1pt}{\hatchdistance-1pt}}%
    {
        \pgfsetcolor{\tikz@pattern@color}
        \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchthickness}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfqpoint{0pt}{0pt}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{\hatchdistance}{\hatchdistance}}
        \pgfusepath{stroke}
    }
    \makeatother
    
\noindent%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand\qText{My school provides me with information about my next steps, for example, choosing qualifications for the futue, going to university or other education and training options like apprenticeships, or finding a job.}
\newcommand\resA{Yes, I received the right amount of information that was helpful}
\newcommand\valA{48}
\newcommand\resB{Yes, but it was too much information and was not helpful}
\newcommand\valB{23}
\newcommand\resC{Yes, but there wasn’t enough information that was helpful}
\newcommand\valC{29}
\newcommand\resD{No, I haven't received any information}
\newcommand\valD{0}
\newcommand\resE{}
\newcommand\valE{0}
\newcommand\ncount{305}
  \begin{axis}[
    axis on top,
    height=7cm,
    xmin=0,
    %width=\textwidth,
    bar width=0.6cm,
    %ymajorgrids, tick align=inside,
    enlarge y limits=true,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left,
    y axis line style={opacity=0},
    ytick=data,
    %tickwidth=0pt,
    enlarge x limits=false,
    title={`\textbf{\qText}'},
    title style={align=left, text width=21cm},
    xbar,
    xlabel={\% of Respondents},
    symbolic y coords={{\resE}, {\resD}, {\resC}, {\resB}, {\resA}},
    y tick label style={align=right, text width=9.5cm},
    %ytick=data,
    nodes near coords, nodes near coords align={horizontal},
    ]
    \addplot[draw=blue!45, samples=100,
        pattern=flexible hatch,
        pattern color=blue!45] coordinates {(\valA,{\resA}) (\valB,{\resB}) (\valC,{\resC}) (\valD,{\resD}) (\valE,{\resE})};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this, worked exactly as I needed. The `\makeatother` is a confusing thing for LaTeX novices like me as often the commands seem to make no sense. Thanks again.

Comment: To me, `\makeatletter` means: "make the @ a letter" (which can be important, since you would normally not be able to use this character, because it is exactly not considered a letter by LaTeX). `\makeatother` then means: "make the @ this other strange thing again, just like before". Just a mnemonic bridge ... See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8351/47927) for more information.